# Help to evaluate determinant

Tags: matrices

I want to evaluate the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix

$\left|\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -a\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & -a & 0\\
&&&\vdots \\
0 & -a & 0 &\dots & 0
\end{array}\right|.$

So I try to say that it is $(-1)^{ n + (n-1) + \ldots n-(n-2)}(-a)^{n-1}$. So power of -1 should be $\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{2} + n-1$. However answer given is $n(n-1)/2$. Where is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, your answer is correct and agrees with the given answer. Here is the reason:$$\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{2} + n-1=\frac{n(n-1)+2(n-1)}{2}+n-1=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+2(n-1),$$
which implies that 
$$(-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{2} + n-1}=(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+2(n-1)}=(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}.$$

Comment: Hint for OP: $(-1)^{2(n-1)} = ((-1)^2)^{n-1} = 1^{n-1} = 1.$

Answer (score 4):

Using cofactor expansion, we have:
$$
\left|\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -a\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & -a & 0\\
&&&\vdots \\
0 & -a & 0 &\dots & 0
\end{array}\right|
=
\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & \ldots & 0 & -a\\
0 & \ldots & -a & 0\\
&&&\vdots \\
-a & 0 &\dots & 0
\end{array}\right|
.
$$

The [determinant of the anti-diagonal matrix](https://planetmath.org/DeterminantOfAntiDiagonalMatrix) in the RHS is give by (note that RHS is $n-1\times n-1$):
$$ \det = \dfrac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} (-a)^n }{(-a)} = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}(-a)^{n-1}.$$